# iOS Custom cell long gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, custom-cell

Help me please to figure out what the magic is going on. What I have is a tableView with custom cells. I don't need to handle long taps, but when one occurs program crashes with message:

> exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType
>   gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xa0836a0'

I've found similar question here [Crash while long press on the tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010706/crash-while-long-press-on-the-tableview), but that solution didn't help me. Actually my handler function doesn't get called when I try to add my own long gesture recognizer. Just annoying error again and again.

More precise what I do here: in

> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

right before returning the cell I have following lines:

> UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture =
>       [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
>   action:@selector(handleLongPress)];
>
> [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

But

> -(void)handleLongPress

almost never getting called. And even if it is, after couple successful times, error occurs again.

One more time: I don't need handle long gesture in any way, I just want it not to cause my app to crash. And the point is that I do nothing special. I've created a class

> @interface NewsViewController: UITableViewController
>   <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
>   UITableViewDelegate>

and now I'm trying to add custom subviews to cells. Everything was fine until I noticed this little issue.

Which by the way disappears when I comment the line

> [cell addSubview:myCustomCell.view];

but this is not what I want.
By the way my table shouldn't be editable, so I also have

> - (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
>     return NO;  }

When I allow editing, it changes nothing. Long tap -> crash. And same message.

May be something is wrong with my custom cell's properties, but I have no idea what exactly. 
One more fact: my table is detailed view in Master-Detail based app.

Thanks for any suggestions and your attention!

Comment: Show us how you set up the gesture recognizer.

Comment: Why aren't you adding your view to the cell content view?

Comment: Please add more code for better understanding.